# I want to print all process numbers with their respective arrival and burst time

Tags: python

```
noOfProcess = int(input("Enter no of processes : "))

print(noOfProcess)

for i in range(noOfProcess):
   arrivalTimes= input("Enter arrival time of P" + str(i) + ": ")
   burstTime = input("Enter burst time of P" + str(i) + ": ")

   list1 = [i+1,arrivalTimes,burstTime]
  # result= list1.values()

print(list1)
```

Comment: I think you are looking for: `list.append()`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.